# How to remove the rows containing all missing data in dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the rows from a tibble that contain missing values.

```
rawdata1 %>% group_by(TAXA) %>% 
  filter(TAXA != "Annelida" & TAXA != "Arachnida" & TAXA != "Fungi" & TAXA != "Mammalia" & TAXA != "Platyhelminthes")%>%
  select(EGGSLAID,CRACKED,VIABLE,
         EMBRYLIVE,EGGHATCH,SURVIVE,GROWTH)%>%                                      
  drop_na()
```

But it keeps returning the same data:

| TAXA | EGGSLAID | CRACKED | VIABLE | EMBRYLIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crustacea | "" | "" | "" | "" |
| Crustacea | "" | "" | 50% | "" |
| Mollusca | "" | "" | "" | "" |
| Insecta | "" | "" | "" | "" |

I think this is because it's not being recognised as NA but I don't know.

Comment: Please show the `dput` of the iinput example.  Also, you may need to assign back `rawdata1 <-`  to update the original data

Comment: I guess the `&` condition should be changed to `|` because you are using `!=`

Comment: would be more compact to use `filter(!TAXA %in% c("Annelida", "Arachnida", "Fungi", "Mammalia", "Platyhelminthes"))`

Comment: Also you can supply specific columns to `tidyr::drop_na()` to specify where you want to disallow `NA` values. Also `""` is not the same as `NA` so `drop_na()` will not do anything on those. Depending on how you are getting your data into R there are usually arguments to import functions to convert various characters or strings to `NA`. This will probably help. But please share actual data to receive actual help.

Comment: Strong support for Dan Adams's recommendations. An empty string `""` is different than a missing value `NA`. You should go back to the command you used to import data and use the arguments for that (usually `na.strings` or similar) to have the empty strings read as `NA` values--then `drop_na` will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option (assuming the structure of the empty string). Here, I convert the empty string to `NA`, then I get the sum of non-NA values for each row and keep only rows that have at least 1 non-NA value. Note: I also included @DanAdams better way of filtering):

```
library(tidyverse)

rawdata1 %>%
  group_by(TAXA) %>%
  filter(!TAXA %in% c(
    "Annelida",
    "Arachnida",
    "Fungi",
    "Mammalia",
    "Platyhelminthes"
  )) %>%
  select(TAXA, EGGSLAID, CRACKED, VIABLE,
         EMBRYLIVE) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(., "\"\""))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(cur_data())) > 0)
```

**Output**

```
  TAXA      EGGSLAID CRACKED VIABLE EMBRYLIVE
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    
1 Crustacea NA       NA      50%    NA
```

**Data**

```
rawdata1 <- structure(
  list(
    TAXA = c("Crustacea", "Crustacea", "Mollusca",
             "Insecta"),
    EGGSLAID = c("\"\"", "\"\"", "\"\"", "\"\""),
    CRACKED = c("\"\"",
                "\"\"", "\"\"", "\"\""),
    VIABLE = c("\"\"", "50%", "\"\"", "\"\""),
    EMBRYLIVE = c("\"\"", "\"\"", "\"\"", "\"\"")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L)
)
```